# Change text using XSLT

Tags: xslt

I am trying to change some text from XML. However it did not work.

I have to display all of `[intro]` text from XML
   some `Path(text)` should change before display `[intro]`.

For example

```
<a href="3DD3D025-2236-49C9-A169-DD89A36DA0E6/eee.pdf"> --> wrong path
```

I would like to change to

```
<a href="Content\3\D\D\3DD3D025-2236-49C9-A169-DD89A36DA0E6/eee.pdf">
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

**Sample XML**

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<root>
  <intro xml:lang="en">
    <div class="blueBar">
      <h2>Highlights</h2>
      <ul> 
        <li><a href="http://xxx/xxx/default.asp?lang=En">aaaa</a></li>
        <li><a href="http://xxx/default.asp?lang=En">bbbb</a></li>
        <li><a href="http://xxx/Content/1/C/D/1CD1DFC3-5149-4D61-A7C3-2D9CF7E65F8C/rrr.pdf">ccc</a></li>
        <li><a href="3DD3D025-2236-49C9-A169-DD89A36DA0E6/eee.pdf">pdf</a></li>
      </ul>
    </div>
  </intro>
  <intro> .....</intro>
</root>
```

**Sample XSLT**

```
<xsl:param name="language"/>

<xsl:template match="root">
  <xsl:for-each select="intro[lang($language)]//@href">
    <xsl:choose>
      <xsl:when test="contains(.,'pdf') and not(contains(.,'Content'))">
        <xsl:variable name="pdfGuid">
          <xsl:value-of select="substring(.,0,36)"/>
        </xsl:variable>
        <xsl:variable name="pdfPath">
          <xsl:value-of select="concat('&#47;','Content')"/>
          <xsl:value-of select="concat('&#47;', substring($pdfGuid, 1,1))"/>
          <xsl:value-of select="concat('&#47;', substring($pdfGuid, 2,1))"/>
          <xsl:value-of select="concat('&#47;', substring($pdfGuid, 3,1))"/>
          <xsl:value-of select="concat('&#47;', $pdfGuid)"/>
        </xsl:variable>       
        <xsl:value-of select="strJS:replace(string(.),string($pdfGuid),string($pdfPath))" disable-output-escaping="yes"/>
      </xsl:when>
      <xsl:otherwise>
        <xsl:value-of select="." disable-output-escaping="yes"/>
      </xsl:otherwise>
    </xsl:choose>      
  </xsl:for-each>

  <div class="greenBox">
    <xsl:value-of select="intro[lang($language)]" disable-output-escaping="yes"/>
  </div>     

</xsl:template>
```

Comment: The xslt doesn't make sense. What does `<xsl:value-of select="intro[lang($language)]" disable-output-escaping="yes"/>` do? Why do you use `disable-output-escaping`?? Could you make a small, full and sufficient example what do you have as xml and what do you want in output.

Answer (score 0):

When you ask a question here, please clearly explain the output you want and what the problem is that you are encountering.

There is a discrepancy between your description of the problem and your attempt, wherein you are using forward slashes, and one at the beginning of the path in your XSLT, and backslashes in your description. I am going to assume you want forward slashes, but these can easily be changed. I suspect what you want is something like this:

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
  <xsl:output method="xml" indent="yes" omit-xml-declaration="yes"/>
  <xsl:param name="language" select="'en'" />

  <xsl:template match="@* | node()">
    <xsl:copy>
      <xsl:apply-templates select="@* | node()"/>
    </xsl:copy>
  </xsl:template>

  <xsl:template match="/*">
    <div class="greenBox">
      <xsl:apply-templates select="intro[lang($language)]/node()" />
    </div>
  </xsl:template>

  <xsl:template match="@href[contains(., 'pdf') and not(contains(., 'Content'))]">
    <xsl:attribute name="href">
      <xsl:value-of select="concat('/Content/',
                                   substring(., 1, 1), '/',
                                   substring(., 2, 1), '/',
                                   substring(., 3, 1), '/',
                                   .)"/>
    </xsl:attribute>
  </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

When run on your sample input, the result is:

```
<div class="greenBox">
    <div class="blueBar">
      <h2>Highlights</h2>
      <ul>
        <li>
          <a href="http://xxx/xxx/default.asp?lang=En">aaaa</a>
        </li>
        <li>
          <a href="http://xxx/default.asp?lang=En">bbbb</a>
        </li>
        <li>
          <a href="http://xxx/Content/1/C/D/1CD1DFC3-5149-4D61-A7C3-2D9CF7E65F8C/rrr.pdf">ccc</a>
        </li>
        <li>
          <a href="/Content/3/D/D/3DD3D025-2236-49C9-A169-DD89A36DA0E6/eee.pdf">pdf</a>
        </li>
      </ul>
    </div>
  </div>
```